# Kubernetes run shell command in deployment container

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod

It is possible to define commands in the Kubernetes for a Deployment that are to be executed immediately after creating the deployment?

for example:

```
cd opt/
wget xxxxxx
mkdir new/
```

I have not found any solution to this problem so far.

Is there any other method to get this effect?

Comment: why not run this commands as part of your pod?

Comment: Have you tried this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/ ?

Comment: I'd probably build this into the image if I could.  If what you're fetching is mostly-static data, do it in a Dockerfile `RUN` intstruction; if it's very dynamic or really can't be built into the image (something like a per-installation security credential) then use an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: busybox
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "cd opt/ &&  wget xxxxxx && mkdir new/ && process-that-keeps-container-running"]
          name: busybox
```

It's a bit tricky, since at the end of the command arguments, you will have to place the command that keeps the containers running. If you don't know which one this is, you will have to look at `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` of the Docker image you are using.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this configuration makes pod status terminated

Comment: ... and an example of the "process-that-keeps-container-running" (if you don't have a proper server installed there) can be an infinite wait loop: `while true; do sleep 10000; done`